# Pass command line arguments to expect command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

I'm trying to write a bash script that will take a username as command line argument. It should login to system with provided username and execute a command.

```
expect -c 'spawn su - other_user_name -c my_bash_command; expect "Password :"; send my_password\n; interact'
```

If I provide the required variables it should be like:

```
expect -c 'spawn su - $1 -c ps ax | grep java | cut -f2 -d " " - | xargs kill -9; expect "Password :"; send Temp/123\n; interact'
```

where `$1` is the passed username, `ps ax | grep java | cut -f2 -d " " - | xargs kill -9` is the command executed by that user. If I pass argument it says no such variable. If I write `#!/usr/bin/expect` at the top of the script, it doesn't work. I need to fix it.

Comment: `$1` is shell syntax and Tcl does not support it. Expect's `spawn` does not support `|` as in shell. it's not easy to write complicated Expect script with `expect -c` because the string quoting would be messy. i'd suggest you write a standalone `foo.exp` and invoke it as `expect foo.exp ...`.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: is `pkill` available on your system? Might be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing pynexj's valid concerns, and passing the username to expect through the environment (and adding newlines for readability):

```sh
env user="other_user_name" expect -c '
    spawn sh -c "su - $env(user) -c ps ax | grep java | cut -f2 -d \" \" - | xargs kill -9"
    expect "Password :"
    send Temp/123\n
    interact
'
```